# NullPointerException when using an array of another class

Tags: java, oop

I created a public class `UnsortedArray` which creates an `int[]` array (random integers), as one of it's variables, when an instance is created. I am using this class instance whenever I want an unsorted array for practicing different sorting techniques.

Problem is it's showing as `NullPointerException` when running but no compilation errors.

Code:

```
public class UnsortedArray 
{

  int[] unsortedArray;
  public UnsortedArray(int size) 
  {
    int[] unsortedArray = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        unsortedArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
 }

public class QuickSort 

{   
 public static void main(String[] args)   
 {

    UnsortedArray arr2 = new UnsortedArray(10);
     //Error:NullpointerException appears here
    displayArray(arr2.unsortedArray);
  }

 public static void displayArray(int[] arr) 

 {

   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

 }
```

When I'm trying to display the array, it's showing as `NullPointerException`. No compilation errors or warnings but run time exception.

Help me Out..!!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
int[] unsortedArray = new int[size];
```

to

```
 unsortedArray = new int[size];
```

you are recreating local `unsortedArray` array instead of initializing instance variable you created earlier

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance variable in class UnsortedArray and it is never initialized. You are adding values to a local array of a method that dies after the constructor has finished. That;s why you are getting null pointer .

Change your code from

public class UnsortedArray 
    {

```
  int[] unsortedArray;
  public UnsortedArray(int size) 
  {
    int[] unsortedArray = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        unsortedArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
 }
```

to

```
public class UnsortedArray 
{

  int[] unsortedArray;
  public UnsortedArray(int size) 
  {
    unsortedArray = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        unsortedArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
public UnsortedArray(int size) 
  {
    int[] unsortedArray = new int[size]; //at this line you create local variable with same name as object variable
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)         //due to that, array is instantiated locally and after executing constructor is going to be destroyed
    {
        unsortedArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
 }
```

to make this work just delete **int[]**. Like that:

```
public UnsortedArray(int size) 
  {
    unsortedArray = new int[size]; //instantiates array for object's variable
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        unsortedArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
 }
```